# Why am I not able to read the complete email body using Exchange Web Service Java API?

Tags: java, email, exchangewebservices, ewsjavaapi, email-body

I am using EWS Java API to read and process emails. One such email contains few conversation and a MS Teams meeting information at the end. While reading such an email, the `EmailMessage.getBody()` returns only the MS Teams meeting information and all the other contents of the email body are ommitted. Sample code below:

`EmailMessage message = EmailMessage.bind(service, new ItemId(item.get(nMessagePos).getId().getUniqueId()));`

`String emailBody = message.getBody().toString()`

I tried setting the `BodyType` property to both HTML and Text and then fetched the body of the email but it still returns only the Meeting invite details.

Is there any specific reason for this and is there a way for me to get the complete email body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to enable tracing https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-trace-requests-responses-to-troubleshoot-ews-managed-api-applications or look at the actually soap responses your getting it could be a parsing issue at the client side (eg bug in the library). You could also try getting the Mimecontent of the Message instead and then parse back the body from that content. Something like EWSEditor might be useful for trying to diagnose what is going on it will show you what the responses look like and allow you to test mimecontent etc without needing to write any code https://github.com/dseph/EwsEditor/releases.

Comment: Thanks, it appears that there was some issue with parsing and I was able to troubleshoot it based on your suggestion.